# How to create mutually exclusive features and change the installation condition

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have some set of features in our product msi.
Of those, two should be mutually exclusive.
i.e., if one selected in the feature screen, automatically, other should be unselected.
So, I created one more dialog “custom setup 1” as a clone of “custom setup” and swapping between these two for refreshing the values.
And, when the feature A is selected, I am using the Remove event to un-select Feature B.

[Dialog Event Behaviour sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq0z7.png)

The dialog is working as expected in UI.

[feature selection page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPcYw.png)

But it raised another problem.
We have some custom actions, which should run anytime other than Uninstallation, i.e., install,repair,etc. So, I kept the condition as "NOT REMOVE".When we unselect the features using the REMOVE. Then these custom actions are being skipped now instead of running, as REMOVE property will have some values even during the installation.

[Custom action condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGt2E.png)

Log : MSI (s) (EC:08) [16:42:01:683]: Skipping action: New_InstallService (condition is false)

Can you suggest an alternative for this?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of **NOT REMOVE**, I am keeping **NOT (REMOVE~="ALL")**

Comment: Are you saying this solved the problem for you?

Comment: yes @music2myear, this condition is solved my issue.